# Reading text file into array of structures C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have been stuck in trying to read this text file into array of structures.Here is a few lines from the text.

```
A|Boston Red Sox|Fenway Park|4 Yawkey Way|Boston|MA|02215|(617) 267-9440|redsox.com
N|St. Louis Cardinals|Busch Stadium|700 Clark Street|St. Louis|MO|63102|(314) 345-9600|cardinals.com
```

Here is the array of structures. I modified the text file so it only contains league and team name to make it easier to test changes.

```
#define LEN_LINE 80
#define LEN_NAME 30
#define MAX_LINES 60
#define LEAGUE_NAME 5

typedef struct
{
    char leagueName[LEAGUE_NAME + 1];
    char teamName[LEN_NAME + 1];


} team_t;
```

Here is where the problem lies.I have tried implementing strncpy() though being a beginner it has been hard trying to use the function correctly in this scenario.

```
FILE * filePtr;
    int index, count;
    char line[LEN_LINE + 1];
    team_t teams[MAX_LINES];
    filePtr = fopen("MLBteams.txt", "r");
    if(filePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
        while(index<MAX_LINES && fgets(line, LEN_LINE, filePtr))
        {
            if(2 == sscanf(line,"%s %s", teams[index].leagueName, teams[index].teamName)

               )
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        fclose(filePtr);
```

I looked through other threads though they've only confused me.

Comment: The problem is that I need to read the information in between these lines | from the text file into separate members of structure. The problem with my code is that it will just read these lines | and for example if I want to read Boston Red Sox into teams[index].teamName it will only store Boston. Also thanks for the link, I will try to break down the code and see if it helps me.

Comment: So that is like a special specifier that reads characters until it runs into |.Since information like phone numbers/zip codes are constant I can just read them as strings.Anyways thank you very much for help.

Comment: After increasing the length of #define LEN_LINE it is working perfectly.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your example of the content of the text file, you have a splitter as | symbol ( A|Boston Red Sox ). You need to put it inside sscanf:

```
if(2 == sscanf(line,"%s|%s", teams[index].leagueName, teams[index].teamName))
{
                index++;
}
```

Ok. Since there are spaces in your strings, you can parse manually its not hard. Instead of code abow do this:

```
char *league_p = strchr(line,'|');
int len = league_p - line;
char *league = calloc(len, 1);
memcpy(league,line,len - 1);
league_p++;
char *team_p = strchr(league_p,'|');
len = team_p - league_p;
char *team = calloc(len, 1);
memcpy(team,league_p,len - 1);
```

This way you will always get first two values splitted

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: `2 == sscanf(line,"%s|%s", ...` will always fail unless a space precedes `|` in the `line`.